# K-Folds validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

Suppose we make a linear regression model on each of the 10 folds with the same number of features (say 2 for simplification)
We will therefore have 10 sets of coefficients with the optimized values ​​of the parameters with each of the metrics (for example R2).

In the end what model do we retain? (the best, the average values ​​obtained for each parameter, the model that obtained the average R2?)
Ouvrir dans Google Traduction

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you are using folds, the final prediction is calculated as an average of all predictions obtained using the models based on folds. 
Linear regression is a special case of ML methods, where averaging the predictions gives the same results as using a model of averaged parameters.
So, regarding your question, in your way of using folds and models, the proper parameters of the final model are the average values ​​obtained for each parameter.

Comment: An important point is that this would not be the same with other types of models, this applies specifically to linear regression.

Comment: Thanks you for your contribution.